# Looking for the content of a list, in another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
alist=[['able'], ['acre'], ['bale'], ['beyond'], ['binary'], ['boat'], ['brainy'], ['care'], ['cat'], ['cater'], ['crate'], ['lawn'], ['list'], ['race'], ['react'], ['sheet'], ['silt'], ['slit'], ['trace'], ['interject'], ['contradict'], ['oration'], ['understandable']]
```

and another list:

```
blist=['co', 'de', 'dis', 'inter', 'non', 'not', 'post', 'pre', 're', 'sub', 'trans']
```

Now my question is, I want to check if the contents of **B list** match any of the content in **A list**, in other words if **A list** has any of the prefixes listed down at **B list**

In the end it's supposed to give me a result like "co" appears once in A list, "inter" appears once in A list etc.

edit, here's a code I tried but didn't work, could someone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
for word in alist:
    if blist in word:
       print word
```

Comment: *Now my question is, I want to check if the contents of B list match any of the content in A list, in other words if A list has any of the prefixes listed down at B list* - that's not a question

Comment: Did you already try anything that isn't working?

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently trying to use??

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no reason to place your strings within nested lists. So here's what I would do:

```
import collections
import itertools

alist = [s for sub in alist for s in sub]
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
for s, a in itertools.product(blist, alist):
    if a.startswith(s):
        counts[s] += 1
```

Comment: because OP mentioned *prefixes*, perhaps change: `if s == a[:len(s)]`?

Comment: It seems like I'm only getting one word (trans).